# Matlab: using fscanf() and having issues

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to use the fscanf() command to read a text file. The text file contains a table of years (in the first column) and across the row is the rainfall for each month in that year. Nothing is in scientific notation. The file is called "OctavilleRainfall.txt", containing following:

```
1988     9.2    5.4 5.6 1.2 2.2 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.4 2.3
1989    12.3    3.4 2.1 1.9 1.2 0.5 0.1 0.0 0.3 0.3 0.5 2.1
1990    10.2    6.7 3.3 1.3 1.1 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 1.9
1991     9.0    2.3 4.8 0.7 0.6 1.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.6 3.4
```

My current code reads as follows:

```
file = fopen('OctavilleRainfall.txt');
A = fscanf(file,'%f',[13 inf])
```

But when A displays, it is in scientific notation.

I'm not sure why it is in scientific notation, as I'm using the format command `f` not `e`. I need it not in scientific notation to be able to do my work. Any suggestions on how to fix this? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `fscanf()`, but rather with the display format Matlab uses. Try changing it to a different format. Simply type:

```
format shortG
```

Note that the display format does not change any of the calculations performed, so it shouldn't affect your work.